# Angular JS update ng-click event on other click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to update argument of ng-click of button but not able to do it please help me... my code is
in controller

```
$scope.trCategoryId = 0;
```

and setting up this value in other function like

```
$scope.setClick = function (CategoryId) {
$scope.trCategoryId = CategoryId;}
```

in html i have define bellow

```
<button ng-click="ActiveTag('step1',{{trCategoryId}},0)" id="btnrename">Create</button>
```

it is not calling up ActiveTag function

Comment: are they on the same scope? why don't you just use trCategoryId on your ActiveTag function?

Comment: {{trCategoryId}} within any `ng-` is a no-no. It evaluates variable names against scope inside automatically, no need for the {{}}.

Comment: firstly remove {{}}. in addition can you show your ActiveTag function?

Comment: this is my activetag function                                          $scope.ActiveTag = function (id, categoryid, rename) {
   
    if (categoryid != undefined)
      
    if (id != 'step1')
        
    if (id == 'step1' && rename == null) {
        $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $('#myUpdateModal').modal('hide');
    }
    if (id == "step1" && rename == 0) {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        $('#myUpdateModal').modal('toggle');
        $('#myUpdateModal').modal('show');
      
    } else { $("#" + id).show() };
   
}

Comment: after removing{{}} problem is solved Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Glad my comment worked out for you, adding it below as a solution:

Angular related attributes prefaced with `ng-` auto evaulate so
{{trCategoryId}} within any ng- is a no-no. It evaluates variable names against scope inside automatically, no need for the {{}}.

```
<button ng-click="ActiveTag('step1',trCategoryId,0)" id="btnrename">Create</button>
```